# TV Mount fixtures on hollow wall with plywood

Tags: drywall, mounting

I'm wanting to mount an 18Kg TV using a universal mount with 6 holes. The positions of the studs are not quite right for where we want the TV to go.

This part of the wall has been built recently to block up an alcove and has 18mm plywood attached to the studs and the plasterboard is attached to the plywood.

What fittings should I use to mount this with? I'm assuming wooden screws would not work since there would only be 18mm of plywood behind.

My first thought was to use a hollow wall anchor like:

[image: hollow anchor]

But the 36mm depth of plywood+plasterboard means I've not been able to find an anchor long enough.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

18mm (3/4") plywood is certainly adequate using proper screws. #14 (7mm or so) wood-thread screws with a proper pilot would hold just fine. Otherwise just use togglers.

[image]

Comment: Surely the #14 screws would need to be longer than 7mm since we have 18mm or plasterboard and then 18mm of ply?

Comment: Both dimensions were referring to nominal diameter, not length. Since most DIYSE users are in the U.S. I provided both.

Comment: Ah ok, what length would you recommend?

Comment: Whatever is necessary. You don't need me to tell you that. :)